# Python ctypes callback function gives "TypeError: invalid result type for callback function"

Tags: python, ctypes, ffi

I was planning on using a C function exported by a DLL in my Python application. This particular function takes multiple callbacks as parameters, so I was fiddling around with defining such callbacks with ctypes in python. However, I quickly got stuck on this simple test:

```
from ctypes import *

someFunction = CFUNCTYPE(POINTER(c_long), c_long)

def someFunctionPy(someLong):
    return pointer(c_long(someLong))


print POINTER(c_long)
print someFunctionPy(1)

someFunctionImpl = someFunction(someFunctionPy)
```

Where `someFunctionImpl` could then be passed on to a C function as a parameter. This gives me the following error:

```
<class '__main__.LP_c_long'>
<__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x022928F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    someFunctionImpl = someFunction(someFunctionPy)
TypeError: invalid result type for callback function
```

The print outputs tell me that the function returns an object of the correct type, so what am I missing here?

Edit: It does seem to work when I use `someFunction = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_long)`, even though `c_void_p` and `POINTER(c_long)` have differing types. Huh?

This doesn't really help though, since eventually I'll have to use a predefined `CFUNCTYPE` that has `POINTER(c_int)` as return type.

Comment: What's wrong with using a void pointer?

Comment: As I mentioned, eventually I'll have to use a `CFUNCTYPE` that someone else has defined and that I cannot edit. That `CFUNCTYPE` has `POINTER(c_long)` as return type.

Comment: Callbacks use the return type's `setfunc` to set the return value in the FFI result buffer. Only simple type's have a `setfunc`, including the simple pointer types `c_char_p`, `c_wchar_p`, and `c_void_p`. Non-simple pointer types, array types, and struct types do not have a `setfunc`, so they cannot be directly returned by a callback.

Comment: Using the `setfunc` won't leak memory for non-pointer types, but it does leak a refcount for `c_char_p` and the encoded `wchar_t *` buffer for `c_wchar_p`. If you set the result type to `c_void_p`, then you can return just the address of a ctypes object. This puts the onus on you to keep the object alive while the C library has access, e.g. in this case you'd need to keep a reference to the `c_long` instance.

Comment: Then why is it used in the following function definition: `MediaOpenCb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.c_void_p, ListPOINTER(ctypes.c_void_p), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint64))`, which comes directly from the libvlc API? (which I assume has been tested)

Comment: I don't see any tests or examples that use that callback in the [GIT repo](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree). File a bug to report that the generated callback definitions won't work. To reiterate, a `_ctypes._Pointer` subclass (i.e. what the `POINTER` factory function returns) doesn't have a `setfunc`, so [`_ctypes_alloc_callback`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.10/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c#l409) raises a `TypeError` (lines 443-457). It has to be a simple type, i.e. a subclass of `_ctypes._SimpleCData`.

Answer (score 5):

This is currently not possible. See [this CPython bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue5710).

Comment: Is this still the case or is it fixed in new python ?

Comment: Still the case, ran into this myself. Still not implemented 15 years later after being initially reported. Bummer.